# Displaying the progress of a Hive query

Tags: python, hive, pyodbc

I am connecting to Hive through `pyodbc`. The connection is successful and I can execute my queries.

I have build a progress function to show me the progress of the job I submit, which is essentially a progress bar. However, I cannot see the progress bar

The standalone function is working, but it is not working when I put it in front of another function.

```py
from time import sleep
import sys
def progress_sec(x):
    for i in range(21):
        sys.stdout.write('\r')
        sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %d%%" % ('='*i, 5*i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.25)
    return
```

The function above is my progress bar function, and I'm trying to put this in front of:

```py
df_hotels = progress_sec(pd.read_sql(sql, con))
```

where both `sql` and `con` have been defined and working.

I want a progress bar showing me the progress of when `df_hotels` line starts execution, but I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: `progress_sec()` only gets called after `pd.read_sql(sql, con)` finishes execution.

Comment: how do I call it initially?

Comment: Call it first, then do `df_hotels = pd.read_sql(sql, con)`

Comment: You need to come up with some sort of metric for tracking the progress of your job. Is it a number of files created? A file created at a certain size? A number of loop executions? Whatever it is, a good design is to have 1 process do the job (which you can open with `subprocess.Popen`) and another process periodically checking the status based on your metric and display your progress bar

Answer (score 1):

pandas' `read_sql` is a blocking call. Once you start a query by calling it, the program will not get a chance to run before the query returns.

You could try to work around this by starting multiple threads (one for the pandas call, another for the progress bar), but I can't confirm that this will work.

You could go further and run the query in a separate process, like [@SyntaxVoid suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417274/why-is-pyodbc-not-using-the-function-i-have-created#comment101314741_57417274), but you'll still have no way to get the execution progress.

If you really want to track progress of a Hive query, you'll might want to give up `pandas` and `pyodbc`, and use a specialized interface, like [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive#db-api-asynchronous); the following is lifted from its README:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM my_awesome_data LIMIT 10', async=True)
status = cursor.poll().operationState
while status in (TOperationState.INITIALIZED_STATE, TOperationState.RUNNING_STATE):
    logs = cursor.fetch_logs()
    for message in logs:
        print message

    # If needed, an asynchronous query can be cancelled at any time with:
    # cursor.cancel()

    status = cursor.poll().operationState

print cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thank you @Nickolay I'll try this and post my answer as to how it works